# TreeMap randomly stops properly returning values

Tags: java, treemap

I have the following TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> distances = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

and it contains both strings, "Face" and "Foo", with appropriate values, such that:

```
System.out.println(distances);
```

Yields:

```
{Face=12, Foo=2}
```

However, `distances.get(Face)` returns `null`, even though `distances.get(Foo)` properly returns 2. Previously, `distances.get(Face)` worked, but for some reason, it stopped working. Note I print out the map *right* before calling get() for both keys, so I haven't accidentally changed Face's value to null. Has anyone else ever encountered this problem? Is there anything I can do? I'm having a terrible time simply trying to figure out how to debug this problem.

NOTE: In the real code I'm not actually using Strings, but a different object, so it's: `TreeMap<Object, Integer>`. So it's not simply a confusion of variable names vs. literal strings.

SECOND NOTE: I also feel pretty confident about my implementations of `hashcode()` and `equals()` for the object I'm using. (Also, if my implementations weren't correct, wouldn't it not work from the beginning? Instead of stopping to work randomly?)

Comment: Do you have synchronized access to the Map? Maybe the values have been removed by another thread?

Comment: No, I haven't synchronized the access, but I don't think I need to. Basically, the calls are in a simple for loop that iterates over the whole map. It doesn't do anything but make get() calls for comparisons.

Comment: -1 - delete this question and start again giving the REAL problem, not some nonsense about `TreeMap<String, Integer>` not working.  And include enough of your actual code to give us a clue ...

Comment: have you assigned the `TreeMap` with a `Comparator` or have your real classes implemented `Comparable`? If so, can you ensure that compare(a,b) == (-1*compare(b,a)) ?

Comment: If you have overriden `toString` for your objects then check that as well. Also use `distances.containsKey` to work out if the key is (a) absent or (b) present and mapped to null

Comment: @smessing This is very likely a broken comparator/comparable. Please post more of your real code. You don't need to delete this question and start again, just edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to your note:  everyone is asking if you've overridden `equals()` and `hashcode()` properly -- which is important, yes.  But this is a `TreeMap`, which means you also have to care about comparisons -- whether you're using `Comparable` objects or an external `Comparator`, you need to make sure that your comparisons are consistent (are your objects mutable?) and that they're consistent with your `equals()` method.

Incidentally, when you said in your original question that you were using `String` objects, you did yourself a disservice -- Strings are immutable and their comparison methods aren't under consideration here, so the question was fundamentally different; now that we know your own code is involved, the field of possible solutions is wider.

Comment: I see your point about the mention of `String` objects, sorry about that.

As for your comment, I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean "make sure your comparisons are consistent"... make sure that my objects aren't changing without me be aware of it? If that's the case, I also feel fairly confident that the objects themselves are not changing in any way. The code this is all in is for sorting amongst the objects, but not for operating *on* them, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the values "Foo" and "Face" are both `Strings`?

This code works for me:

```
        TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("a", 1);
        map.put("b", 2);

        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(map.get("a"));
        System.out.println(map.get("b"));
```

Will output {a=1, b=2}
1
2.

In your case, if `Foo` and `Face` are not both `String`s, the map can not use them as keys for a lookup. Maybe you are using `get(Face)` where you should use `get("Face")`?

Comment: See comment on other answer, but basically, I'm not actually using Strings, I'm using a different data type. Strings were for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing the string literal `"Face"` with a variable called `Face`?  If you're literally using `distances.get(Face)`, that means you're trying to pass in a variable `Face`, and it's not surprising that you're getting `null` back out (unless that's a String variable whose *contents* you've previously added to the map).

Instead try `distances.get("Face")`.  If that works, it means `"Face"` is the string you're using as a key -- which isn't the same as a variable `Face` that might contain a string.

Comment: Sorry, this needs clarification: in my actual code I'm using different objects (my own data type), so the confusion you speak of can't be what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

@smessing did you properly implement `equals` and `hashcode` methods on your class that objects Foo and Face belong to?
When you want to store an object in a List, Map or a Set then it is a requirement that equals and hashCode are implemented so they obey the standard contract as specified in the  documentation.
If these are not properly done, a get operation can result in unexpected results as you mentioned.

Comment: I have implemented both, and feel fairly confident that they aren't the problem. Also, remember that for a while the get() calls return the proper values, but at some point stop...

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning Face with some other reference object/variable, check if that is becoming null.

If your face object is pointing to the reference of another object and the other object sets it to null, Face also becomes null.